# unable to instal Mahotas python library

Tags: python, computer-vision, anaconda

I am unable to install Mahotas python library on my pc. I try to install it by using the pip installation. But when i try it returns the following error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpxRD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Author of mahotas here. The recommended installation method is to use conda-forge. It should support all major operating systems:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mahotas

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual C++ Build tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Restart your machine and then try

`pip install mahotas`

If you have conda installed, you can install mahotas using the following pair of commands:

`conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install mahotas`